# retrieve latest primary key of table to use as foreign key in different table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 and would like to know, if there is a fast way to retrieve the **primary key** created during the last insert statement in **table A**, so I can use it as **foreign key** for different insert statement in **table B**. For example, first add a new car brand in one table, then add some models of the brand in a different table.

```
TABLE car_brands (
brandID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
name TEXT
)

TABLE car_models (
modelID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
brandID INTEGER REFERENCES brandID,
name TEXT
)
```

**sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()** is no option, since I do not know if another thread is updating the database during this operation.

Will I have to retrieve it using a separate statement?

Greetings,
curiosity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the online help, both `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()` and `last_insert_rowid()` (for use within SQL) are connection specific.

As long as you ensure multiple threads are not sharing the same connection, you won't get concurrency issues with `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()`.

And within your SQL statements, one connection can only be running one query.  Provided you have both the INSERT and the call to `last_insert_rowid()` within the same batch, that shouldn't have concurrency issues either.